# how to transform a double into an array of bytes in c

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am writing a program in c that runs on 32-bit Microcontroller. I have a double and I want to transform it into an array of bytes. These bytes will be later sent to another microcontroller. But I do not know which method I should use to perform this task. Any Suggestion?
**The Problem consists in the inability in c to define a function that returns an array. So I must define an array outside the function and then process it inside the c-function which does not satisfy my needs**

Comment: A function can return a struct or union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type-punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) through a union:

```
union{
    double d;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(double)];
} d2b;

d2b.d = 3.14;
```

You can access the bytes through `d2b.bytes`. Note that this assumes both micro-controllers use the same (internal) representation for `double`s. If not, use some sort of [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

**Edit:**

Seeing your edit. You could also just `memcpy` and 'return' it through an output-parameter:

```
unsigned char * doubleToBytes(unsigned char bytes[sizeof(double)], double d){
    return memcpy(bytes, &d, sizeof d);
}
```